# RequiredFieldValidator and styling

Tags: .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Is it possible with the standard .Net field validators to change the style on the textfield, in which the error occures?

If I e.g. have a field phonenumber which needs to be filled out, it should create a red border around the textfield on submit, if the field is not filled.

Hopefully this can be done with the standard controls so I don't need to recode it using e.g. jQuery Validation plugin etc.

-Dofs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a native components from ASP.Net:

In your ASP page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateTextBox1"   ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

In the code behind:

```
    protected void ValidateTextBox1(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) 
            {
                if (TextBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                    TextBox1.Style.Add("border", "solid 1px red");
                    CustomValidator1.Text = "required";
                }
                else
                    args.IsValid = true;

            }
```

**PS.: On press button, the RequiredFieldValidator is activated before the CustomValidator. If there are any on the same page, you have to turn it off or replace it with CustomValidator.**

OR

You can do with a CSS and Javascript.

CSS Class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:10pt;
    }
    .ErrorControl
    {
        background-color: #FBE3E4;
        border: solid 1px Red;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
 if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
    for (var i in Page_Validators) {
        try {
            var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
            if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                control.className = "ErrorControl";
            } else {
                control.className = "";
            }
        } catch (e) { }
    }
    return false;
 }
 return true;
}
</script>
```

Now, the validators ASP.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

OR

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction="Validate"></asp:CustomValidator>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate).value != "") {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the ajax toolkit, as explained by Lance Zhang [on this page](http://forums.asp.net/p/1406723/3065026.aspx).

Comment: I would like to do it with the regular asp.net controls and not be dependent on 3rd party controls.

Comment: How is Microsoft a third party? It's an open source library but it's still made by Microsoft.